# are #flurry supporting Swift Package manager

Tags: swift, flurry, swift-package-manager

I'm not a big fan of cocoa pods, and are trying to modernise a project, getting rid of all the cocoa pods for a start, and #flurry is one of them. is there a Swift Package manager implementation of #flurry

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so no. Swift package manager is comparatively new so it would take time for developers to port their cocoapods to SPM. But, there is already a request to add SPM support that has been closed, due to the unavailability of support to add binary in SPM. Check this [link](https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/issues/174).